# How to determine the user that forked a repo into my organization?

Tags: github, git-fork

I am trying to determine who created a fork from a repo in another github organization. For example, in the organization `https://github.com/companyA`, someone created a fork from the `https://github.com/companyB/instructions` repo as `https://github.com/companyA/instructions`. How can I view the initiator?

I have looked through the Settings and Insights sections of my github organization in the fork from the other organization. I am unable to find who created the fork. I've looked in history and did not find the creator. I've searched for "how to determine who forked a repo into my organization in github" and with similar wording but have been unable to find the information. The results mostly point to "who forked **my** repo, not who forked **their** repo along with forks and how to manage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a direct way to determine who forked a repo into your organization in GitHub.

> I have looked through the Settings and Insights sections of my GitHub organization in the fork from the other organization. I am unable to find who created the fork. I've looked in history and did not find the creator

That means the fork has been created, but no commit has ever been done.

Check if [listing fork](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/forks?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-forks) is enough.
I use the [GitHub CLI `gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api)

```bash
C:\Users\vonc>gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /repos/VonC/batcolors/forks --jq "sort_by(.created_at) | .[] | {login: .owner.login, created_at: .created_at}"
{"created_at":"2020-01-23T12:25:04Z","login":"jeb-de"}
{"created_at":"2022-01-29T14:25:31Z","login":"canarddu38"}
```

That should work for their (public) repositories, not just yours.